# Is it possible to locate images in storage and then display them?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a music app, and I'm trying to search my storage for songs and then display the cover art on the layout.

I'm already able to display the song name and album.

```
private void loadSongs() {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    //String selection =
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                Song newSong = new Song(name, artist, album, url);
                songs.add(newSong);
                displaySongs.add(name + "\n" + album + "\n" + artist + "\n" + url);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

}

public void showSongs() {

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    displaySongs = new ArrayList<>();
    loadSongs();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, displaySongs);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You'd basically need to get the image from the URI and set it to an `ImageView`. I'd probably recommend you to use a image loading library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to reduce the boilerplate code and not have to worry about caching and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must get the Uri or the Url of the image location.

I suggest you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the image into an ImageView.

First import Glide in your `module:app`

```
dependencies {

    ...

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

}
```

To use Glide :

```
 Glide.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```